# How do I strip Arm-R-Seal?

Tags: finishing

I'm looking for some good methods for removing Arm-R-Seal Satin from a dining table as I had some problems with bubbles in part of the finish. Not sure what else to do other than remove it and start again? Is sanding the best approach or do I need to use some sort of chemical stripper?

Comment: Good photos of the problem area would help get better responses here. If the bubbles are big enough that they extend through the whole varnish coat then you are probably best in removing it all and starting again. But if they're small and largely sitting at the surface then you can get rid of them by wet-sanding and applying one or more extra coats, see other current Question, [Problem with “Bubbles” in Table Finish. Please Help](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/5163/problem-with-bubbles-in-table-finish-please-help).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, arm-r-seal is basically a polyurethane varnish, so that would be the direction to investigate for chemical strippers. Unless you are sure the table top is solid wood, be careful when sanding to make sure you don't go through veneer. Furniture scrapers might be another approach; they can take a very thin layer off something if handled correctly.That's how I did my most recent refinishing job, though it was a simple one.)